Empty array after adding the first item
I want to pass an object array to LocalStorage. But after the first record is added, an empty array is passed, and only after the second record is added, 1 record is passed, after the third record is added, the array already has 2 records.
<button onClick={() => {
    setCustomArr([...CustomArr, { item1: null, item2: null, item3: null }])
    localStorage.setItem("localStIt", JSON.stringify(CustomArr))
  }}
>Add item</button>

This is what the code for the button looks like, when clicked I add a new entry to the array, and populate the current array into LocalStorage. And I get an array with one record only after the second click, but after the first click the array is empty.
Why does this happen and how to fix it?
const [NewCustomArr, setNewCustomArr] = useState()

<button onClick={() => {
        setCustomArr([...CustomArr, { item1: null, item2: null, item3: null }])
        setNewCustomArr(CustomArr)
        localStorage.setItem("localStIt", JSON.stringify(NewCustomArr))
      }}
>Add item</button>


Setting state is asynchronous; you’re using it before state resolution. Create the new value and use it for both updating state and putting into localstorage.

@DaveNewton, i got it. Could you show me a code example, please?

Create the new value and use it for both updating state and putting into localstorage. Make a temp variable and use it in the setState and set to localstorage.

@DaveNewton, I've updated the question with the new value. Please take a look. Do you mean this?

Does this answer your question? The useState set method is not reflecting a change immediately

Since setting state is asynchronous action, you should use setState callback pattern to get current state and set updated state properly. Here is an example:
<button 
    onClick={() => {
        const newItem = { item1: null, item2: null, item3: null }
        setCustomArr(prevState => {
           localStorage.setItem(
               "localStIt", 
               JSON.stringify([...prevState, newItem])
           )
           return [...prevState, newItem]
        })
    }}
>
    Add item
</button>

Or you can assign the updated value to a variable and use that for both operation.
<button 
    onClick={() => {
        const newItem = { item1: null, item2: null, item3: null }
        const updated = [...customArr, newItem]

        setCustomArr(updated)
        localStorage.setItem(
            "localStIt", 
            JSON.stringify(updated)
        )
    }}
>
    Add item
</button>


setCustomArr with useState is async operation, so you need to assign a variable for the value update and use it for both operations (local storage and state updates)
const [NewCustomArr, setNewCustomArr] = useState()

<button onClick={() => {
        //this variable is to store the updated value of the state
        const updatedArray = [...CustomArr, { item1: null, item2: null, item3: null }]
        setCustomArr(updatedArray)
        setNewCustomArr(updatedArray)
        localStorage.setItem("localStIt", JSON.stringify(updatedArray))
      }}
>Add item</button>

